# Why did my angle grinder die?

Tags: repair, powertools, electric-motor

I was recently using a Bosch angle grinder but it had been 'sputtering' intermittently; and then during one session, taking the burrs off an edge, it slowed down and just stopped. Now it won't turn on. Does anyone know why this happened? Can it be repaired? Could it have been repaired or serviced before it finally died? I need to know if only for future reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Intermittent "sputtering" is sign of a loss of power going into the motor windings. there is pretty much only two ways this happens, A: there is a short somewhere (plug, cable or switch) or B: the contact brushes are dead.

[image]

If mild shaking of the grinder added to the sputtering, I would say its the brushes. This is an easy fix, since you just need to get access to the brushes and change them. However, for many cases (with cheaper makes) its about the same cost to replace the unit.

Comment: +1 I also see it as a contact brushes problem. I'm sure You can try it to to it by yourself (if varranty is not valid).